# Animate ui.router transitions

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate, animate.css

I am trying to animate the transitions of the ui router.

To do that I am using `animate.css` and `angular-animate`, but I have a problem:

when the transition happens, the exiting view drops down before sliding left (the new view pushes it down).

the `less/css` code to animate is:

```
.main_view {
  .transition(all 10s);

  &.ng-enter {
    .view-wrapper {
      .fadeInRight;
    }
  }

  &.ng-leave {
    .view-wrapper {
      .fadeOutLeft;
    }
  }
}

.view-wrapper {
  .transition(all 0.5s ease-out);
  .animated;
}
```

every view is wrapped with the `view-wrapper` class like this:

```
<div class="view-wrapper">
   ... view content ...
</div>
```

I made a demo with two states in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pweVNMDYb7xTGmNtNE1E?p=preview

How do I prevent the exiting view from dropping down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I set

```
.main_view{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It's working but there's maybe a better solution

**EDIT**
With  @ryeballar comment you can put:

```
.ng-enter{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Works well.

Comment: It would be better to put that in the `.ng-enter` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not really working for me since I have a `footer` in my site and then the views go over the footer, and that's not really good. I know I can hack it and make it work like that, but would rather a better solution... Thanks though!

Comment: Ok I think I got it: http://plnkr.co/edit/fz8ob3t0qGcVFZ4HwgDk?p=preview

I create a parent on index.html with position: relative and put position:absolute & top:0 on the .ng-leave.

Is it ok for you?

Comment: Looks good, but I'm still unsure... I will use it as a last resort.